# How do I configure ssh to ask me for my password in the terminal instead of in a dialog box?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-mate

On Ubuntu Mate, whenever I try to push to github, I get a dialog asking me to "Enter password to unlock the private key", instead of it it prompting me in the terminal.  How do I configure ssh to ask me for my password in the terminal instead of the dialog?

Comment: Possibly related on [so]: [using the git client on a headless linux server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348688/using-the-git-client-on-a-headless-linux-server)

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/684937/124862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently started seeing the same behaviour (for years it asked in the terminal).
I think it turns out that having a id_rsa.pub in your ~/.ssh directory is what triggers the behaviour.
I recently put it in there so that i could ssh-copy-id to one of my other servers.
You could work around the issue by storing your public key elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

### SSH Key Passphrase

You generally want to **keep** an **ssh-key** **locked** with a **passphrase**. But you can remove the passphrase security and you will stop receiving the prompt.

### Ubuntu - GUI

Ubuntu comes with a program called **Passwords and Keys**. This software will let you manage many *security credentials* in **Ubuntu**.

[image]

[image]

Steps to disable private key passphrase:

1. Go to **OpenSSH Keys** and find the private key you use to access *GitHub*.
2. **Right Click** the key you want to modify.
3. Select **Properties**.
4. Press <kbd>Change Passphrase</kbd>.
5. Enter **current** passphrase.
6. Leave the prompt empty for the next two prompts about the new passphrase. (This will leave the key unlocked permanently or until you set a new passphrase.)

### I DO NOT RECOMMEND

Although this will stop the prompt I do not recommend keeping an ssh-key unlocked for security. If however you know this file will be secure on your private computer and you don't have access to high risk information go ahead.

Just remember:

> "You don't necessarily know what you want to keep a secret, until it is not a secret anymore."
>
> > ```
> >                                       -I forget the reference.
> > ```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I don't want to disable password prompting altogether; I jsut want it to ask me in the terminal, instead of in a dialog window.  I updated the question, to reflect these clarifications.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`man ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`. You run `ssh-add` to pass the pass phrase for your private key to ssh-agent (assuming that ssh-agent is running). Whenever ssh needs a pass phrase and ssh-agent is available, ssh will ask ssh-agent for the pass phrase instead of asking you.

Note:You need to run ssh-add for all your private keys once per session.

Comment: I don't want it to ask ssh-agent.  I want it to ask me in the terminal.  I updated the question to include these clarifications.  Thanks.